# Cumlative count of unique values of a variable per user in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to set an order value of what emails have been opened per user.
Basically a script that counts and sets when the  emails were read for a user.

```
Users   Emails     Date_Sent    Date_Opened   Count
user1   email a    01/1/2015    02/1/2015     1
user1   email b    12/3/2015        
user1   email c    08/5/2015    10/5/2015     2
user1   email d    04/6/2015    04/6/2015     3
user1   email e    05/8/2015    05/8/2015     4
user2   email b    06/1/2015        
user2   email c    07/1/2015    08/1/2015     1
user2   email d    14/2/2015
```

So far I've tried this code

```
data$count <- with(data, ave(Emails, Users,
                   FUN = function(x) cumsum(!duplicated(x))))
```

It works by counting the emails per users. I'm still figuring out how it'll limit it by just those that have a data in the Date_Opened field.

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[Date_Opened!='',Count := 1:.N , Users]
```

Or

```
 setDT(df2)[Date_Opened !='', count:= cumsum(!duplicated(Emails)) , Users]
```